# Reset variable value when page refreshs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

this is simple js script for clearing and recovering input value, onFocus-Blur..
it works well, but if I type there ane text for example : aaa, than refresh the page and clear input value
by Backspace button or by another way It saves 'aaa' in my defaultValue variable and then recovers cleard input value in 'aaa' not 'search'...

Is there any Function or Method in javaScript(jQuery) which clears Variable memory after refreshing the page,
not reloading by url-PressEnter.. Only refreshing by F5 or with refresh arrow button in browsers?

you may check that in FireFox, couse in Chrome there is no problem, Chrome does it itself.

Hope someone help.. : (

thanks ))

```
// clear-fill search input
var mySearch = $('input[name=newsSearch]');
var defaultValue = mySearch.val();
mySearch.focus(function(){
if($(this).val() == defaultValue ) {
$(this).val('');
}
});

mySearch.blur(function(){
if($(this).val() == '')  {
$(this).val(defaultValue);
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In modern browsers that support html5 elements you can use the [`placeholder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-placeholder) attribute on an `input` to do this without any javascript:

**HTML**

```
<input name="newsSearch" type="text" placeholder="Search" />
```

And you can add some javascript to support older browsers that do no support the placeholder attribute:

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function add() {
        if ($(this).val() === '') {
            $(this).val($(this).attr('placeholder')).addClass('placeholder');
        }
    }

    function remove() {
        if ($(this).val() === $(this).attr('placeholder')) {
            $(this).val('').removeClass('placeholder');
        }
    }

    // Create a dummy element for feature detection
    if (!('placeholder' in $('<input>')[0])) {

        // Select the elements that have a placeholder attribute
        $('input[placeholder], textarea[placeholder]').blur(add).focus(remove).each(add);

        // Remove the placeholder text before the form is submitted
        $('form').submit(function () {
            $(this).find('input[placeholder], textarea[placeholder]').each(remove);
        });
    }
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EDRkF/2/)**

**Further reading**

- [Javascript fallback](http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/form-placeholder-text/)
- [Alternative javascript fallback](http://www.scriptiny.com/2012/08/html5-placeholder-fallback-using-jquery/)
- [Information](http://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder)
- [Browser support](http://caniuse.com/input-placeholder)
- [More demos](http://www.wufoo.com/html5/attributes/01-placeholder.html)
- [How to style](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/style-placeholder-text/)

Comment: Yea I know that but I don't want to use HTML5, I prefer to have old browser support too.

thanx))

Comment: Have a look at the javascript fallback I have linked to. It gives a fallback to browsers that don't support `placeholder`.